# Is it possible to overlay tr with transparent color and text?

Tags: html, css

Good evening.

I wanted to ask, that is it possible to overlay table row with some transparent color and text?

Something like this:
[image]

I found from stackoverflow that its possible to overlay   over  using css, but never managed to get it to work.

If its possible, maybe someone can point me to right way.

For example how to overlay middle table row with transparent color and text here:

```
<body>

<table border="1" style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>      
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>        
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>        
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gx2vpm62/  ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you need the overlay text to be the same on each row?

Comment: I mean overlaying it when the mouse's over?

Comment: No i dont mean with mouse over, i want to overlay certain row with color or shadow, and also add text in center of the overlay. Text can be same on overlay.

Answer (score 12):

You can do this by using an absolutely positioned element in the table. I don't know about cross browser support for this solution and the spacing is static.

```css
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(255,0,0,0.7);
  left: 0.7em;
  right: 0.7em;
  height: 1.2em;
  text-align: center;
}

tr {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <table border="1" style="width:100%">
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eve</td>
      <td>Jackson</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td class="overlay">Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>80</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: For your solution is it possible to add text in the center of overlay ?

Comment: Works, but kinda messes up the table layout itself and is harder to implement than a pure CSS solution, which only involves setting a class, not changing the actual content of the table

Comment: Difficulty is subjective and depends on the application.

Comment: Only adding a class is of course a less complex action than adding a td (with a class as well) and therefore changing the table structure itself. But actually I dont want to argue ;) maybe we can agree that in many cases, different solutions have different strengths and weaknesses?

Comment: Sure, that's what I was getting at :D. @frontend_dev

Comment: Yeah, and also depends if the OP wants to do that in a dynamic way or just with static HTML.

Answer (score 6):

Its even possible to do this by pure CSS, but can be a bit finnicky to make it perfectly align. Try this:

```css
table {
border-collapse: separate;
border-spacing: 0;
border-color: transparent;
overflow: hidden;
}
td {
position: relative;
height: 1.5em;
padding: 0;
border-color: transparent;
}
td:first-child {
width: 40%;
position: relative;
}
td:nth-child(2) {
width: 40%;
}
td:nth-child(3) {
width: 20%;
}
.overlay td:first-child:after {
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
display: block;
text-align: center;
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 252%;
height: 1.5em;
content:"text";
background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .7);
color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <table border="1" style="width:100%">
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="overlay">
      <td>Eve</td>
      <td>Jackson</td>
      <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>80</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>
```

**Update:** now should also work in Chrome, but I really havent tried to get it working in every browser on this planet, so keep this in mind before downvoting me again. I just want to help.

Additional trickery involved applying the `:after` rule on the `td`, not the `tr`. But you have to know the relative width of the td to calculate the overall width of your overlay, and then you still don't get always the exact width matching the table. Therefor the slightly "overshoot" and the `overflow:hidden` to mask that issue.

Comment: 1+ I just upvoted.. but I wanted to point out that this doesn't work in Chrome. It looks like Chrome doesn't position the pseudo element relative to the `tr`.

Comment: This is exactly what i had in mind, but any idea why it doesnt position on a row that has this overlay class ? http://prntscr.com/95q9lt

Comment: Chrome seems somehow not allow to play with tr (table-row) layout. but for simple effects, maybe turning tr into table, you may, then, insert a pseudo as a table-caption and play with margins http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/QjPYqN or worse line-height and box-shadow http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dYLaRg . maybe that's an hint . best would be to use javascript and insert a div over from a relative container parents of table to avoid to use table or its elements as relative.

Comment: OK, at least an explanation. Yeah sorry tried this in FF only.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to post my solution as current answers are hacky / not flexible.

This solution requires `tr` to have a `position: relative` and `td` to have position `static` (as it is per default). Then you need to insert `div.overlay` in any of `td`'s and then it's just styling.

Example:

```css
body {
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 16px;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}

table tr {
  position: relative;
}

table td, table th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  backdrop-filter: blur(1px);
}

h2 {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px black;
}

samp {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  padding: 2px 6px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>
      94
      <div class="overlay">
        <h2>Overlay with custom <abbr title="HyperText Markup Language">HTML</abbr> spanning over <samp>tr</samp></h2>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```